# Disk brake issues

Tags: brakes, disc-brake, brake-pads

I’m new to disc brakes and noticed my braking power decreasing. Took the pads off and they look like this. Do these lines indicate anything? What is a used disc brake pad supposed to look like? What’s the solution?[image]

Comment: Mechanical or hydraulic, makes a big difference to answers. Mechanical its likely pad adjustment or contamination, hydraulic its likely contamination or need bleeding.

Comment: Also a measurement of the remaining pad thickness (excluding backing) and the make/model of the brakes. Those pads look like the ones on my MTB with (not great) hydraulics.  The stripes are probably the areas that encounter more rotor surface, and probably don't mean much, but could indicate a bit of contamination.  (How) have you cleaned any parts of the brakes?

Comment: VTC as no further information has appeared